# External hard drive not detected in Ubuntu & Windows machines, it makes some noise when I connect it in any machine

Tags: 16.04, external-hdd

In my Ubuntu I tried:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

But it gives me a red line :

```
Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

I am unable to solve this issue. I also tried :

```
ls /dev/ | grep sd
```

My external drive not showing here

```
sda
sda1
sda2
sda5
```

Can someone help me ?

[image]

Comment: If your external disk makes noises it might be damaged. Trying with another usb cable and different usb slots could be worth trying. Can you show, right after connecting the usb disk, the relevant output of the command : dmesg

Comment: It does sound from  your description that the hard-disk is damaged. Are you able to reformat that drive?

Comment: not start on physical sector boundary means that your hard disk partitions are not properly aligned... but that's not your current problem. Use the `Disks` application to look at the SMART data/tests on the drive... and see what SMART tells you.

Answer (score 0):

not start on physical sector boundary means that your hard disk partitions are not properly aligned... but that's not your current problem|||| i want to smash my head, becouse u say this if is irrilevant...most of the problem of exsternal hardisk r of course, becouse they r incompatibile and the drive /windows/linux/ubuntu/ dont reconize the hardisk it sels so what to do u need to try if u r lucky with varius metod
1 chenge the setting in the bios help alot ....try to esperimental change the setup of the sata
2 try to change the cable
3 boot with another hardisk that u know is working with a operating sistem  and check if your machine can see the hardisk...